# Django redirect not working with registration

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
ValueError at /
The view landing.views.base didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/?ex=tset1&adalt=1
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view landing.views.base didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: /var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 139
Python Executable:  /var/www/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

This is error with django 2.0.7
Anybody have idea?

EDIT : the view code:

```
def base(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # set form and valid
        r_form= forms.RegisterForms(request.POST)
        if r_form.is_valid():
            usr = models.YammyUsers()
            usr.contact = r_form.cleaned_data['f_contact']
            # usr.dt_reg = timezone.now()
            # usr.exchange = ex
            # usr.adalt = bool(adalt)
            # usr.source_url = sourse
            usr.save()

            c['r_form'] = r_form
            return redirect(reverse('complete'))

    else:
        r_form = forms.RegisterForms(request.GET)
        ex = request.GET.get('ex', '')
        adalt = request.GET.get('adalt', 0)
        if request.META['HTTP_REFERER']:
            sourse = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        else:
            sourse = ''

        c['r_form']=r_form
        return render(request,'landing/forma_reg.html',c)
```

Comment: Did you **`return`** the `redirect(..)`? Looks like you did not...

Comment: You need to show your code, not just the error.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  +1

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
def base(request):
    # code here...

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # set form and valid
        r_form= forms.RegisterForms(request.POST)
        if r_form.is_valid():
            # code here...
            return redirect(reverse('complete'))

    else:
        r_form = forms.RegisterForms(request.GET)
        # code here...
        return render(request,'landing/forma_reg.html',c)
```

your first return statement is only executed if it's a POST request AND the form is valid, and your second return statement is only executed if i's a GET request, so if it's a POST request and the form is not valid, the function ends without an explicit return and so implicitely returns `None`

The fix is quite easy actually: just de-indent your last return statement, so an invalid form will be redisplayed with it's error messages:

```
def base(request):
    # code here...

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # set form and valid
        r_form= forms.RegisterForms(request.POST)
        if r_form.is_valid():
            # code here...
            return redirect(reverse('complete'))

    else:
        r_form = forms.RegisterForms(request.GET)
        # code here...

    # make sure we ALWAYS return a response
    return render(request,'landing/forma_reg.html',c)
```